# Passing a variable as a parameter in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to call a function which nulls the field clicked,

if I write `(focus)="this.element.task=null"` , it works but if I do `(focus)="resetFields(this.element.task)"` is there a way to achieve this?

resetFields method:

```
resetFields(elm) {
    elm = NULL;
    this.submitted = false;
}
```

Sample on Stackblitz:  http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvgtec

Comment: Can you create a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue?

Comment: i guess you should try  `(focus)="resetFields(element.task)"`

Comment: What's happening when you try to call it?  What error-messages are being produced on the console?  I immediately notice that you said that `resetFields` is a *method* ... but it looks like a function to me.

Comment: What @MohamedAliRACHID is true, your stackblitz says `onfocus=...` should instead be `(focus)=...`

Comment: in your stackBlitz link it is working with `<input  [(ngModel)]="name" (focus)="resetFields(name)">` , with `(focus)` not `(onfocus)`

Comment: your sample is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is pass by value, only for objects the value is the reference to that object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

So the answer to your original question is no. You cannot modify something inside the function and see the results outside the function as the changes are visible in current function scope. You can only send object to that function and modify that object.

```
resetFields(elm) {
    elm = NULL;  //won't work, will only set reference to elm to null inside resetFields function scope
    elm.someProperty = null; //will work
}
```

You could however do it like this:

```
resetFields(elm, property) {
    elm[property] = null;
}

(focus)="resetFields(this.element, 'task')"
```

Updated [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbwprq).

Answer (score 0):

Try `(focus)` instead of `onfocus` this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" (focus)="resetFields()">
```

Since you're binding to `name` via `[(ngModel)]`, changing `name` in your Component will also change your template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **reactive forms** then ...

```
this.form.reset(); // it will reset all data to blank
```

If you are using **ngModel** then

```
<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="form.name" (focus)="resetData()">

resetData(){
   this.form = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are data binding to a variable in your component called `name` via ngModel, and then passing the same variable back to the component from the template/UI as an argument to the method `resetFields(name: any)`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" (focus)="resetFields(name)">
```

Because you are passing a "copy" of name from the teamplate/UI as an argument to your method resetFields, it is in fact modifying that copy of name, but it does not alter the original that ngModel is using... and because you never do anything with the argument after you modify it... it does not work.

```
 resetFields(name: any) {
    console.log(name);
    name = null;
    console.log(name);
  }
```

This is why modifying the component variable works as you are modifiying the original copy that ngModel is data binding to.

```
resetFields() {
    this.name = null;
  }
```